# AForge.Video / Materialskin repeatedly causing stackoverflow

Tags: c#, winforms, aforge

Ok I am using Materialskin and AForge to make a good application that can have camera previews, show them in a picturebox and then be able to be saved.

this is the portion of the code I think is causing errors

```cs
        VideoCaptureDevice videoSource;

        private FilterInfoCollection VideoCaptureDevices;
        private VideoCaptureDevice FinalVideo;
        int imgCropHeight = 300;
        int imgCropWidth = 500;
        int imgCropX = 400;
        int imgCropY = 300;
        bool isCameraRunning = true;
        public async void AForgeLoadDevice()
        {
            VideoCaptureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            foreach (FilterInfo VideoCaptureDevice in VideoCaptureDevices)
            {
                cameraList.Items.Add(VideoCaptureDevice.Name);
            }
            cameraList.SelectedIndex = 0;
            await Task.Delay(90);
        }

        public void AForgeOpen()
        {
            try
            {
                FinalVideo = new VideoCaptureDevice(VideoCaptureDevices[cameraList.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
                FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
                FinalVideo.Start();
            } catch(Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void AForgeClose()
        {
            FinalVideo.Stop();
        }


        async void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Bitmap video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            Crop crop = new Crop(new Rectangle(imgCropX, imgCropY, imgCropWidth, imgCropHeight));
            Bitmap newImage = crop.Apply(video);
            pictureBox1.Image = newImage;
            await Task.Delay(50);
        }
```

I have tried to do using blocks while creating new forms but that hasn't fixed anything. I never recieved a stackoverflow error in visual studio so I don't understand it too well, but all I know is it said that it had to have happened due to a framework like AForge / MaterialSkin

Any fixes?It would be really helpful.

I think it has something to do with the NewFrameEvent handler because its really the only way for a stackoverflow to be caused

EDIT: This usually happens after keeping the form open for a long time (1 minute+) or closing and recreating (I have an onclose event that stops aforge video feed)

Comment: it also happens instantly sometimes, like as soon as it gets started after 3-5 sec it auto closes.

Comment: `Bitmap`s are Disposable and you appear to be created two new ones on every video frame. I expect that could put a lot of pressure on the GC. Why don't you declare them outside the method and re-use the same references?

Comment: Run your application under the debugger and look at the call stack when it occurs. BTW: what's the reason for the Delay at the end of the event handler? It might not do what you expect.

Comment: the reason for the delay is that I was trying to figure out if the new event handler running was the same as an infinite while loop, and for the people that will use it they don't need the camera at very high fps just a camera preview. Also I was trying to do using block on new form to maybe stop the stackoverflow because they click a button to open this form up, and then they close it and open it up again.

Comment: I tried your solution crowcoder and for now it hasn't given a crash yet. Thanks!

Comment: also for the future, is there a way to specifically find the exact function where a stackoverflow will be caused